# Delphi 3x байтовое число

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Скажите какой тип использовать для 3х байтового числа?
Или если нет как сделать свой тип числа.
Нужно именно 3 байта. Тк считываю структуру такую из файла и всю структуру описываю в record. 
Хочу чтоб числа сразу ложились в переменные без особых трудностей.
Как быть?

Comment: Массив из трех байтов вас не устроит?

Comment: А в связи с чем необходимость таких мучений, вместо использований обычного integer или longint? Процессор обрабатывает операнды по 4 байта, поэтому 3 байтовых типов данных скорее всего в природе не существует. Вы идете в разрез с архитектурой оборудования. 
Либо Вам придется писать свои функции для сложения/умножения деления трехбайтных массивов

Comment: А чем вам не угодил 4-ех байтовый тип?

Comment: Лучше для обработки использовать 4-х байтные структуры, то есть integer, а при чтении и записи их преобразовывать, если, возможно, стоит вопрос об экономии места для очень больших объемов данных. В любом другом случае код будет более медленный либо неоправданно более сложный. В Delphi специально придумано выравнивание (Project option - record field alignment) для того, чтобы ускорить код.

Comment: Я не могу изменить структуру, которая пишет аппаратура ХХХ, т.к. создавалась эта машина не мной.
Да я получаю массивом 3 байта, хорошо как мне их преобразить в 4 байтовый integer, мне я так понял он подойдет, но для красоты структуры хотелось бы 3, если нельзя, то как преобразовать в integer эти 3 байта?
Хотя это не integer, потому как счет от нуля идет, без минусов, это 3 байта, метка времени в секундах

Comment: Либо если производительность не критична то MyIntValue := a[0] * 65536 + a[1]* 256 + a[2],  если в a[2] - старший байт, то MyIntValue := a[2] * 65536 + a[1]* 256 + a[0]. Красота обернется подводными камнями, не рекомендую.

Comment: Integer от longint отличается тем, что в старшем байте крайне левый разряд - знак. Вам без разницы, что использовать.

Comment: Первый байт из этих трех - младший или старший?

Answer (score 2):

С учетом

> Тк считываю структуру такую из файла

думаю, что вы используете для этого TFileStream или другой наследник TStream.

Не помню, какие штатные функции разрешены в D7, поэтому в примерах использую те, которые 100% есть.

```pascal
type
  T3Bytes = array[0..2] of integer;
// судя по комментариям - эта процедура вами не будет использоваться
// поэтому ее вызовы я закомментировал.
procedure Transform3SubZero(var Value: integer);
begin
  if (Value and $800000)<>0 then // если старший бит установлен
    Value:=Value or $FF000000); // то число отрицательное
end;

// если младший байт - впереди
function Transform3BytesToIntLE(Bytes: T3Bytes): integer;
begin
  Result:=0; // обнуляем старший байт
  Move(Bytes[0], Result, 3); // копируем в Integer
  //Transform3SubZero(Result); // если числа могут быть отрицательными
end;

// если старший байт - впереди
function Transform3BytesToIntBE(Bytes: T3Bytes): integer;
var
  tmp: Byte;
begin
  // меняем порядок байт
  tmp:=Bytes[0];
  Bytes[0]:=Bytes[2];
  Bytes[2]:=tmp;

  Result:=Transform3BytesToIntLE(Bytes);
end;

function Load3BytesIntFromStreamLE(Stream: TStream): integer;
var
  Bytes: T3Bytes;
begin
  Stream.Read(Bytes[0], 3);
  Result:=Transform3BytesToIntLE(Bytes);
end;

function Load3BytesIntFromStreamBE(Stream: TStream): integer;
var
  Bytes: T3Bytes;
begin
  Stream.Read(Bytes[0], 3);
  Result:=Transform3BytesToIntBE(Bytes);
end;
```

структуру лучше держать не в record-ах, поскольку D7 не позволяет использовать функции в них, а в классах, так будет проще считывать данные:

```pascal
TmyStruct = class
public
  Field1: integer;
  Field2: integer;
  procedure LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream);
end;

procedure TmyStruct.LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream);
begin
  Field1:=Load3BytesIntFromStreamLE(Stream);
  Field2:=Load3BytesIntFromStreamLE(Stream);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте массив длиной 3 байта

```
T3Bytes = array[0..2] of Byte
```

или запись

```
T3Bytes = packed record
  x: Byte;
  y: Byte;
  z: Byte;
end;
```

Comment: Уточните, как его использовать для случая топикстартера?